# EventArgs can not be serialized in WCF , Generic callback event

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, events, callback

Suppose these Data Contracts:

```
[DataContract] 
public class TestTabularPoint_C 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Modality { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string StudyDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PatientName { get; set; } 
    public TestTabularPoint_C()
    {

    }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(TestTabularPoint_C))]
[KnownType(typeof(TestTabularPlot_DTO))]
[KnownType(typeof(IEnumerable<TestTabularPoint_C>))]
public class TestTabularPlot_DTO : EventArgs
{
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<TestTabularPoint_C> TestTabularPoints { get; set; } 
}
```

And callback event in full session duplex service :

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> FigureDataSetLoaded; 
    public void OnFigureDataSetLoad(EventArgs dto)
    {
        FigureDataSetLoaded?.Invoke(this, dto);
    }
```

at the end the test method:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Tabular_Plot_Based_Cloud()
    {
        DispatcherClient dc = new DispatcherClient(new DispatcherCallBack(), "dispatcherEndPoint", Internals.SYSTEM, Cluster);
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ManualResetEvent ev = new ManualResetEvent(false); 
            dc.FigureDataSetLoaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                TestTabularPlot_DTO dtoOut = (TestTabularPlot_DTO)e;
                Console.WriteLine(dtoOut.TestTabularPoints.Count());
            };
            var res = dc.TestTabularPlot(new ModalityReport_DTO_IN()
            {
                From = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-50),
                To = DateTime.Now
            });
            ev.WaitOne();
        }).Wait(dc.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout);
    }
```

when debug the above test method the `FigureDataSetLoaded` event not raised and debugger goes to CCU !!!! and not respond, but when I changed that event to notify client `TestTabularPlot_DTO` when it is not derived from `EventArgs` everything works fine,

in the other side when I removed the `KnownType` attribute , the exception get raised as:

> Type 'x.TestTabularPlot_DTO' with data contract name 'TestTabularPlot_DTO:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/x' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.

1- Why derived class from `EventArgs` can not be serialized and what is the solution ?

2- is there a way to have generic call back event in WCF ?

Such:

```
 public event EventHandler<T> FigureDataSetLoaded;
```

and pass different DTOs to client by one event.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any feedback, comment ? is there someone has already encountered this ?